# define nagios command with "&&"

Tags: nagios

Have a following nagios command, with this command_line:

```
command_line curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"title\": \" ** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert - $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **\", \"text\": \"***** Nagios Admin *****\n\nHost: $HOSTNAME$ ($HOSTALIAS$)\nAddress: $HOSTADDR$" && php /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/manage-host-tickets.php hoststate="$HOSTSTATE$" hoststatetype="$HOSTSTATETYPE$" eventhost="$HOSTNAME$" hostattempts="$HOSTATTEMPT$" maxhostattempts="$MAXHOSTATTEMPTS$" hostproblemid="$HOSTPROBLEMID$" lasthostproblemid="$LASTHOSTPROBLEMID$"
```

They are two separate tasks that are separated by "&&" and work individually. 
This way don't work. I am calling this command in the hosts event handler.

Comment: Try replace `&&` with `;`.

Comment: Thanks Rohlik. It was my mistake. The commands were not exactly the same as what I was doing individually.